# Do all nodes have to be stored / indexed in a GNN?

Tags: python, graph-neural-network

Apologies in advance for what maybe a really silly question :(

I am trying to construct a Graph Neural Network, in which I would like to learn representations for certain nodes, but not others. To be concrete I have a dataset of URLs which contain the title of the page, and the domain on which that URL title appeared so simply my dataset is a tuple `(title, domain)` and I would like learn `node` embeddings for all of my `domains`.

Now I understand that this could be done without a graph, but the above is just the first step of a larger model.

So the issue I am trying to work through is how do I avoid creating an explicit node in my graph for each `title` feature. In a normal model I would say build an embedding for each character or word in my `title` feature - which means I do not need to index each individual title.